# What is the "Heavies" mode in Halo multiplayer?

Tags: halo-the-master-chief-collection, halo-series

In the Master Chief Collection, this mode is currently a part of the [action sack](https://www.halopedia.org/Action_Sack) playlist in at least Reach. I presume that the mode is a variant of the [big team battle](https://www.halopedia.org/Big_Team_Battle) with a higher amount of vehicles and/or increased vehicle spawns, but can't say for sure. The player health seems identical ([Elite slayer](https://www.halopedia.org/Elite_Slayer) has more resistant shields).

Comment: Also it says you get bonus points for "special objectives" and I haven't the slightest clue what those are. My guess is destroying vehicules? Maybe getting kills while in a vehicule?

Comment: @CoqPwner: Interesting, where the "special objectives" is exactly mentioned?

Comment: During loading, you also clearly see the scores reflecting this. People have a higher score than kills. This is in BTB Heavy, not sure about 4v4

Answer (score 1):

According to my research from [Halo Waypoint forum](https://www.halowaypoint.com/en-us/forums/6e35355aecdf4fd0acdaee3cc4156fd4/topics/heavy-game-btb/3a0b7f5c-a33a-4a1e-93d6-7fcf7d4b7346/posts?page=1), you are right "Heavies" mode is a variant of BTB Heavy but for action sack (4vs4). So you will play with lots of vehicles as Tanks/Wraiths/Banshees ... and lots of heavy weapons as Sniper rifle/Laser/Rocket...